# Separate URL for a specific page

Tags: pages, urls

I have 3 sections to a website, each it's own page.

A page for the company and one each for the two founders. Each of the founders would like their page to be under their own domain, but still be able to update from the main Wordpress site.

At the moment I am using iframes for their pages, but obviously this is not a great way of doing it. Can I set a custom URL for specific pages?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Uhm, nice question. Some hacking is required.

1. Use pretty-permalinks on company site
2. On the domain of the founder, do a URL-rewrite from http://www.founder-domain1.com to http://www.companysite.com/page-founder1
3. On the company site, use a custom menu with a custom URL: Founder Page -> http://www.founder-domain1.com. (If you cannot use a custom menu, create a link in your template)

Of course, page-founder1 is the slug for the founder1 page that is edited via Wordpress.
Substitute the domains as your needs.

**Note:**

Beware that you ARE depending on the slugs of the pages of the founders. If you change the slug, you must change the URL rewrite on the founders site.

Comment: Could you possibly give me an example htaccess, I'm having a bit of trouble masking the URL, not just redirecting? `RewriteRule ^$ http://www.google.co.uk [NC]`

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [MultiDomain plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/multidomain/).